# Linq IGrouping, ILookup or IDIctionary divide and map into new IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to map a database model to a view model, at the same time as dividing into a true false lookup on a property that is not mapped accross:

The mapped property will be something like

```
public IDictionary<bool,IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> 
   NoConsentAttemptReasons { get; set; }
```

Such that I can iterate through

```
foreach (SelectListItem item in NoConsentAttemptReasons[true])
```

but I am unsure of the Linq to achieve this. Tried multiple permutations including:

```
model.NoConsentAttemptReasons = ScreenService
       .GetNoConsentReasons()
       .ToLookup(r=>r.Unaware, r => new SelectListItem
{
   Text = r.Description,
   Selected = model.NoConsentAttemptId == r.Id,
   Value = r.Id.ToString()
});
```

but of course I am not mapping to <bool, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> but rather  <bool, selectListItem>

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you *actually* want your property to be of type

```
ILookup<bool, SelectListItem>
```

Don't forget that [`ILookup<TKey, TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx) is declared as:

```
public interface ILookup<TKey, TElement> : IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>
```

(Also implementing the non-generic `IEnumerable`, but let's ignore that for now.)

So any element of the lookup already implements `IEnumerable<TElement>` - you almost certainly don't need an extra layer of `IEnumerable<>` round it.

For example, if you *do* declare the property as:

```
public ILookup<bool, SelectListItem> NoConsentAttemptReasons { get; set; }
```

then you can write:

```
foreach (SelectListItem item in NoConsentAttemptReasons[true])
{
    ...
}
```

This *doesn't* implement `IDictionary<,>`, but it's actually simpler this way - because a lookup will return an empty sequence for an unknown key, instead of just failing.

(In the version of the question I started answering, the property was of type `ILookup<bool,IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>`. I'm not sure why you changed that to `IDictionary<bool,IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>`, but I still think you want `ILookup<bool, SelectListItem>`.)

Comment: Thank you - you were absolutely correct I didn't need the extra layer - thank you very much